# Как вызвать Promise.all для неопределенного количества функции в Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, асинхронность

Есть следующий код:

```
return Promise.all([asyncFunc(var1), asyncFunc(var2)]);
```

А надо что то вроде:

```
var arrayToAsynCall = [];
for(val in params){
    arrayToAsynCall.push(asyncFunc(val));
}
.............
return Promise.all(arrayToAsynCall);
```

Возможно ли такое технически в Js? 
Как добавить адрес вызова функции с параметром (не исполняя ее) в массив?

Comment: ну так а ты пробовал свой вариант? :-)

Comment: Мои вариант не пройдет потому как этот оператор arrayToAsynCall.push(asyncFunc(val)) добавит в массив результат вызова функции, а не точку входа

Comment: а что по твоему возвращает `asyncFunc`?

Comment: asyncFunc = точку входа. 
asyncFunc() = результат вызова функции.

Comment: Тогда почему ты пишешь, что _добавит в массив результат вызова функции, а не точку входа_? если результат вызова и есть _точка входа_? :-) Я так понимаю ты Promise так называешь

Comment: результат вызова это то что идет на выходе

Comment: У тебя весьма странная терминология, но если у тебя работает первый вариант кода, то будет работать и второй вариант, с той же функцией `asyncFunc`.

Comment: @dreddred может быть вы хотите выполнять несколько `asyncFunction` **последовательно**?

Answer (score 1):

Давайте начнем с конца:

> Как добавить адрес вызова функции с параметром (не исполняя ее) в массив?

Иными словами, задача сводится к получению из функции одного аргумента функции с нулем аргументов. В функциональном программировании такое действие назвается [каррированием](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). В JavaScript оно делается при помощи метода [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
var f = function(a) {
    console.log(a);
}
var f1 = f.bind(null, 'some text');

f1(); // Выведет "some text"
```

Однако в вашем случае **эта операция не нужна**.

---

Все дело в том, что вы (похоже) не правильно понимаете назначение Обещаний (Promise).

Основное назначение Обещаний - дать вам возможность обработать результат **когда** он будет доступен. Обещание, возвращаемое методом [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) будет выполненено, **когда** все обещания, переданные в качестве его аргумента будут выполнены.

Код, что вы приводите в вопросе **абслоютно верен**, но давайте разберем его по частям:

```
let arrayToAsynCall = [];
// Обходим каждый элемент массива/объекта params.
// ЗАМЕЧАНИЕ: Я заменил for...in на for...of, потому, что конструкция
// for...in проводит итерации по ключам массива/объекта, а не по его значениям.
for(let val of params){
    // Здесь вы выполняете несколько асинхронных действий последовательно.
    // Что бы все работало, функция asyncFunc должна возвращать обещание.
    arrayToAsynCall.push(asyncFunc(val));
}

// А здесь вы возвращаете Обещание, которое выполнится, когда выполнятся
// все обещания из массива arrayToAsyncCall. Тем самым вы можете определить
// момент КОГДА все ваши параллельные асинхронные действия будут выполнены.
return Promise.all(arrayToAsynCall);
```

Таким образом, если исходный код:

```
return Promise.all([asyncFunc(var1), asyncFunc(var2)]);
```

работает верно, то и вариант с циклом тоже будет работать верно.